# Problemas para guardar Objetos en php

Tags: php, array, poo

Quiero guardar varios conjuntos de datos en un arreglo lleno con objetos, pero en lugar de guardarse todos al mismo nivel, parece que el primero no tiene indice y el segundo es el 0.

```
if($carrito->id_producto == $id_producto){
                        #Si ya el producto esta en el carrito
                        $carrito->unidades = $carrito->unidades + 1;
                        JsonManager::set_json($carrito);
                        $carrito = JsonManager::codificar();
                        $_SESSION['carrito'] = $carrito;
                    }else{
                        #Cuando el producto NO esta en el carrito
                        $carrito = $_SESSION['carrito'];
                        require_once("models/utiles/JsonManager.php");
                        JsonManager::set_json($carrito);
                        $carrito = JsonManager::decodificar();
                        $nuevoProducto = [
                            "id_producto" => $id_producto,
                            "precio" => $precio,
                            "unidades" => 1,
                            "objeto" => $datos
                        ];
                        $carrito = get_object_vars($carrito);
                        $carrito[] = $nuevoProducto;
                        JsonManager::set_json($carrito);
                        $carrito = JsonManager::codificar();
```

uso get_object_vars para convertir a $carrito en un arreglo asociativo, luego le ingreso el nuevo elemento, con la sintaxis $carrito[] = $nuevoProducto; y tambien intente con array_push() pero este siempre es el resultado:

> ```
> stdClass Object
> (
>     [id_producto] => 4
>     [precio] => 40.00
>     [unidades] => 2
>     [objeto] => stdClass Object
>         (
>             [queryString] => SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id=4;
>         )
>
>     [0] => stdClass Object
>         (
>             [id_producto] => 5
>             [precio] => 10.00
>             [unidades] => 1
>             [objeto] => stdClass Object
>                 (
>                     [queryString] => SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id=5;
>                 )
>
>         )
>
> )
> ```

De esa forma no puedo trabajar bien en un for para poder continuar agregando mas elementos sin que se me haga un desastre. Alguien sabe porque no puede simplemente guardarse asi elemento[0] y elemento[1] en lugar de guardar el segundo como subindice del primero?(O eso parece segun entiendo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "*...parece que el primero no tiene indice y el segundo es el 0*"

En el siguiente ejemplo, vemos qué sucede:

```php
<?php
class MiClase {
    public $id_producto = 'ID001';
    public $precio = '40.21';
}

$obj = new MiClase;

$nuevoProducto = [
    "id_producto" => 'ID005',
    "precio" => '172.28'
];
$carrito = get_object_vars($obj);
$carrito[] = $nuevoProducto;
var_export($carrito);
```

El resultado es:

```txt
array (
  'id_producto' => 'ID001',
  'precio' => '40.21',
  0 => array (
    'id_producto' => 'ID005',
    'precio' => '172.28',
  ),
)
```

Como se puede ver, [get_object_vars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) devuelve un array de **una dimensión**, y los elementos **si** tienen índices, pero son asociativos. Recordar que un array en PHP puede tener múltiples tipos de datos, incluyendo elementos asociativos junto a elementos con índice numérico.
Lectura recomendada: [PHP Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Entonces, para "arreglar el problema" en este ejemplo, solo hay que añadir el resultado de `get_object_vars` como un sub-array dentro del array de resultados:

```php
// ...
$carrito[] = get_object_vars($obj);
$carrito[] = $nuevoProducto;
// ...
```

El resultado será:

```txt
array (
  0 => array (
    'id_producto' => 'ID001',
    'precio' => '40.21',),
  1 => array (
    'id_producto' => 'ID005',
    'precio' => '172.28',),
)
```

Comment: Excelente, gracias, me ayudo bastante ;)